# Pauses between actions in jQuery or normal Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a game and I want it to do certain things with 2 second pauses between each thing.

Because it's not a jQuery wrapped selection, I can't use delay().  The problem with the code below is that the RedFlash() function is happening before the pause.  Maybe I need one big function that runs functions out of an array with a 2 second pause between each.

```
// Attack Phase
function attackPhase() {
  animateMessage("You slash with your weapon!", "red");
  window.setTimeout(function() {
     animateMessage("You dealt 15 damage!", "red");
  }, 2000);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
     $('.card_hp').redFlash();
  }, 2000);    
}
```

In the abstract, it's this:

```
// action
// pause 2 seconds
// action
// pause 2 seconds
// action
// pause 2 seconds
// and so on
```

I found several answers to how do I pause once, but not how to pause several times and have each action wait the whole 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to put actions in a queue and execute them one after another with interval of 2s. Also next time you activate an action it will be posted to the same queue and will not start until all previous actions complete.

```
var queue = [],
    timer,
    processQueue,
    animateMessage,
    attackPhase;

processQueue = function processQueue(force) {
  if(!timer || force) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      if(queue.length > 0) {
        queue.splice(0,1)[0]();
        processQueue(true);
      } else {
        timer = null;
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
};

animateMessage = function animateMessage(msg, color) {
  console.log(msg);
};

attackPhase = function attackPhase() {
  queue.push(function(){
    animateMessage("You slash with your weapon!", "red");
  });
  queue.push(function() {
    animateMessage("You dealt 15 damage!", "red");
  });
  processQueue();
};

attackPhase();
attackPhase();
```

Here is a working example http://jsbin.com/akagin/4/edit

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is because you are essentially initiating both `setTimeout()` functions simultaneously.

```
// Attack Phase
  function attackPhase() {
    animateMessage("You slash with your weapon!", "red");
    window.setTimeout(function() {
          animateMessage("You dealt 15 damage!", "red");
          window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('.card_hp').redFlash();
           }, 2000);
    } , 2000);
 }
```

Note: This is not very well-written code. You should set your setTimeouts to a `var` so you can `clearTimeout(var)` if need be. There are lots of other things that should be considered too, but are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: You probably also want to disable certain input/commands to happen in the paused state, as it might trigger a chain of animations and waits.

Comment: Wow super fast reply!  Ok yes I should really clean up this code.  Thank you for the direction.  I see you put them within each other.  Got it.